# In Ruby irb, can't access a number in a array like fashion

Tags: ruby

I tried this in irb:

```
x = 123456
```

Then I wanted to get a specific position of the number like:

```
puts x[2]
```

it returns 0

why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only (sensible) way to do this is to first convert it to a string then use the `[]` method:

```
x_str = x.to_s
puts x_str[0..2] #prints "12"
```

If you want to retrieve the position of a string within another string, use the `index` method

```
puts x_str.index('2') #prints 1
```

`Fixnum` *does supply a `[]` method*, but it's obviously not what you want.

[image]

In your code, it's returning `0` because that is the 3rd (zero-indexed) bit in the binary representation of `123456`.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Numbers are not arrays.

Comment: @Brian True, but strictly speaking, `Array` objects are not arrays either. :)

Comment: Shh. You're only confusing things. :-)

Comment: @Brian Clapper: Well, they *are* kinda-sorta arrays of bits, which is actually what the OP was confused about in the first place.